# is it good to add padding to container-fluid to make sure each device has the same space from left and right

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have created one page later on i came to know that the page is not   responsive.

Now i am recreating the page and have a doubt whether to use
 **container** or **container-fluid** i have read some blogs using of
 container-fluid will be good so i am using container-fluid.

But i am not getting space from left and right so could i use *padding

 : 80 PX* from both the sides will it effect any other
 devices(laptop,tablet,mobile)?

Answer (score 0):

**container-fluid means width:100%, on all devices.**

But by adding `padding 80px` on both sides, the site will look good on desktop, laptop or maybe on tablet.

But on small devices you will be wasting `80 + 80px` space on both sides.

Therefore the content will get squeezed on mobile devices.

The solution for this is to removed the 80px padding on small devices using media-queries
or you can use `container` instead of `fluid`, where this spacing is automatically handled

for example

```
    .container-padding{
     padding-left:80px;
     padding-right:80px;
    }

    @media(max-width:767px){ /*for mobile phone */
     .container-padding{
      padding:15px;/*little padding to your content so that it doesnt stick to the sides*/
     }
    }
```

Comment: yeah on small device it was looking terribly bad so i just removed container-fluid and started using container but for each break point it is showing different sizes as there is a media query involved